# setText is working for the first time only in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, settext

Currently I am working on a music player application and I would like to change the text of a button.

Here is my code . playM is a "Play" button while stopM is to stop, the logic is when the play button is pressed , the text of playM change from "Play"(the default text of playM is "Play") to "Pasue". Then when the stopM is pressed , the playM change from "Pause" to "Play"

However, the actual behavior is when I hit playM is change text from Play to Pause but when I hit stopM the playM does not change from Pause to Play. How to fix the problem ? Thanks

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Song> {
    Button playM = null;
    Button stopM = null;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_view, null);

        }

        p = items.get(position);

        if (p != null) {

            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            Button del = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            playM = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            stopM = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button3);

            String title = p.getTitle();
            String singer = p.getSinger();

            if (tt != null) {
                tt.setText(title);
            }
            if (tt1 != null) {
                tt1.setText(singer);
            }

            del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    db.deleteSong(p);
                }
            });

            playM.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    //if (!manager.isMusicActive()) {
                        playM.setText("Pause");
                        Intent svc=new Intent(getContext(), Music.class);
                        svc.putExtra("uri", tt1.getText().toString());
                        getContext().startService(svc);
                    //}
                }
            });

            stopM.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    playM.setText("Play");
                    Intent svc=new Intent(getContext(), Music.class);
                    getContext().stopService(svc);
                }
            });
        }

        return v;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in an adapter so you can't save item Views like that.

fastest, but probably not the best, solution is to set playM as `final` so that you will be able to access the right button in the listener.

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Song> {
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {

        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_view, null);

    }

    final Song p = items.get(position);

    if (p != null) {

        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Button del = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final Button playM = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button stopM = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button3);

        String title = p.getTitle();
        String singer = p.getSinger();

        if (tt != null) {
            tt.setText(title);
        }
        if (tt1 != null) {
            tt1.setText(singer);
        }

        del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                db.deleteSong(p);
            }
        });

        playM.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                //if (!manager.isMusicActive()) {
                    playM.setText("Pause");
                    Intent svc=new Intent(getContext(), Music.class);
                    svc.putExtra("uri", tt1.getText().toString());
                    getContext().startService(svc);
                //}
            }
        });

        stopM.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playM.setText("Play");
                Intent svc=new Intent(getContext(), Music.class);
                getContext().stopService(svc);
            }
        });
    }

    return v;

}
}
```

Comment: Faster than me...! that's the answer ;)

Comment: Thanks, one more question , if I am using ListView to implement a songlist, each row for one song , how can I ensure the button I click is actually stop / play for that row? (e.g. I press play button in row1 then I press stop button in row2....)

Comment: well i guess you want to have the correct "p" instance right.
define a local final variable like for the play button instead of keeping track of it. Or you can also define position as final and use getItem() from the listener. edit: i updated the code.

Comment: Sorry.confusing for the Ptype as it should be a Song object, what should I do after change the p from Song to Ptype? thanks

Comment: that's should make it. Nothing more, now in the OnClickListener you are using the Song object you retrived in the same getView(...) call.

Comment: ehi if that solved your problem could you accept the answear please?

Answer (score 0):

Please try invalidate to make the change.

```
 playM.setText("Play");
 playM.invalidate();
```

Comment: Thanks. tried but not working. The stopM function (stop service) is working, but only the setText part does not work

Comment: that's because you are changing the text of a "random" view in the adapter. It's wrong to keep a list item view in the adapter like that cause it changes every time an item is created/binded